# overriding equals method with same class strategy vs instance of strategy

Tags: java

Today I come across two different ways of the overriding the equals method. The first one is with `same class strategy` which is:

```java
public boolean equals(Object aPerson){
    if(aPerson == null) return false;
    if(aPerson.getClass() != this.getClass()) return false;
    Person p = (Person) aPerson;
    return this.name.equals(p.name);
}
```

and with `instance of strategy` to be like below:

```java
public boolean equals(Object aPerson){
    if(aPerson == null) return false;
    if(!(aPerson instanceof Person)) return false;
    Person p = (Person) aPerson;
    return this.name.equals(p.name);
}
```

Do both of the implementation work the same way in any condition? Or do they have exception of working for one some times and not working for the other in special case?

My questions focuses on `!(aPerson instanceof Person)` and `aPerson.getClass() != this.getClass()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference when it comes to subclasses of `Person`. The first implementation (`Class` ==) would consider a `Student` and a `Teacher` both named `Alice` to be different. The second (`instanceof`) would consider them equal.

Also, using `instanceof` may violate a contract of the [`equals()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

> •It is *symmetric*: for any non-null reference values `x` and `y`, `x.equals(y)` should return true if and only if `y.equals(x)` returns true.

This can happen if `Student` overrides `equals()` and uses `instanceOf Student`. In that case, checking `student.equals(person)` may return false, while `person.equals(student)` returned true.

In general, it depends on your requirement.

Comment: Therefore, `instanceof` might create asymmetric equals depending on the implementation of equals in the subclass.

Comment: @KidusTekeste Yes correct. FWIW, when auto-generating `equals()` and `hashCode()` in Eclipse (which in general it is a good idea to rely on the IDE to do it), Eclipse by default does not use `instanceOf`.

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

First, `if(aPerson.getClass() != this.getClass())` uses == to compare objects. Yes, theoretically, the "same" class should always result in the same class object, but when different class loaders are in play, strange things could happen. So you would definitely want to use `equals()` here.

Then: the first one only "matches" when `this` and `aPerson` are really objects of the **same** class. So this is prone to fail, as soon as you are dealing with more than one way how `x instanceOf Person` could be true. (like Person being an interface with different subclasses).